# angular, вставка в textarea шаблон html

Tags: javascript, angular

есть компонент в котором поле textarea принимает любой шаблон **html/css/js**
нужно создать **preview** этого шаблона с полностью рабочим кодом шаблона (стили, скрипты, классы стилей)

1. 1й вариант - костыль через перенаправление на другую страницу
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

минус в том что в консоле куча ошибок валит,
2. 2й вариант это через бэк, но дальше нет идей

дополнения
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
вот (редактор) упрощенный, в нем шаблон

и кнопкой preview нужно вывести рабочий код

- 1 вариант вывести в другом компоненте
- 2й вариант вывести в другом окне

Comment: Не понятно что вы хотите, что-то похожее на ck-editor или что-то другое. Дайте больше пояснений, что за textarea. Или вы генерите новую страницу или что? Если вы хотите сделать поле, в которое можно  вставить страницу, то проще сохранить такое на бэке и отдать это как один файл. Кажется, что стоит еще подумать над тем, чтобы пересмотреть задачу.

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Comment: Кажется, что самым простым в понимании будет такой вариант: сохраняем текст в качестве html-файла, например `template.html`. После чего отдаем его по какому-то пути, например `localhost://template/html`. Можно открывать его или в новой вкладке или в iframe. Я бы сделал так. Но в целом, вариантов куча.